# PHP+cURL Post not returning the expected result

Tags: php, post, curl

I am trying to post to a site using PHP and cURL and get a search result as part of a scraping proof of concept. But the response is not the same as the one that I get by accessing the site directly. I have captured all the post parameters and the headers using FireBug and am sending all of them using cURL, but still the response is not the same. Could someone please help out in figuring out what could I be doing wrong?

The site I am trying to access is: http://book.goindigo.in/skylights/cgi-bin/skylights.cgi

In that site I am doing a oneway search which will return a bunch of flights (for example, Bombay-Delhi for September 25). I am not worried about this result. Once the flights are displayed, if a particular flight is picked, it displays the fare breakup on the left side under the Price Summary section. To get this price summary they are firing an ajax call, which is what I want to simulate using PHP and cURL.

When accessed through the site, the ajax call returns a bunch of javascript variables as response. But the same call returns the complete html of the page and NOT the expected javascript variables when accessed through cURL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
$url='https://book.goindigo.in/skylights/cgi-bin/skylights.cgi';

$header = array("Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",     "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5", "Connection: keep-alive", "Cache-Control: no-cache", "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate", "Content-Length: 342", "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", "Cookie: __utma=1.649498667.1346160326.1346395277.1346415046.4; __utmz=1.1346160326.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=1.11.10.1346415046; __utmc=1", "Host: book.goindigo.in", "Pragma: no-cache", "Referer: https://book.goindigo.in/skylights/cgi-bin/skylights.cgi");

$user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0";

$referrer = 'https://book.goindigo.in/skylights/cgi-bin/skylights.cgi' ;

$post_params="page=INCLUSIVE_PRICING&module=SB&sid=&adults=1&children=0&language=EN&infants=0&numberMarkets=1&market1Data=201209036E%20146BLRDEL%20ININERE0BLRDEL201209031345201209031630Regular%20Fare%20ADULT%20ADT%2001&market2Data=&flt1_cnx1_date=&flt1_cnx2_date=&flt1_paxType1_fare=440000&flt1_paxType2_fare=&itin_type=Domestic";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
```

Comment: Maybe the API checks Referer.

Comment: I have tried passing the referer, didn't work. I basically replicated the entire set of headers and post parameters as was sent by the original request using the site page.

Comment: I just captured the post parameters with Chrome developer tools, and sent them using curl from the command line, and I got the expected javascript variables. Can you post your PHP code?

Comment: I have added the code to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
```

Here's what I did from the shell:

```
curl -d "page=INCLUSIVE_PRICING&module=SB&sid=&adults=1&children=0&language=EN&infants=0&numberMarkets=2&market1Data=201209116E   176BOMDEL                            ININERE0BOMDEL201209111325201209111530Regular Fare            ADULT ADT 01&market2Data=201209116E   175DELBOM                            ININNRN0BOMDEL201209111345201209111555RoundTrip Fare          ADULT ADT 01&flt1_cnx1_date=&flt1_cnx2_date=&flt2_cnx1_date=&flt2_cnx2_date=&flt1_paxType1_fare=443000&flt1_paxType2_fare=&flt2_paxType1_fare=402000&flt2_paxType2_fare=&itin_type=Domestic" http://book.goindigo.in/skylights/cgi-bin/skylights.cgi
```

The output was:

```
<!--
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//    Copyright(c) 2000 - 2006 Navitaire Inc.  All rights reserved.         //
//                                                                          //
//    This source code is protected by copyright law and international      //
//    treaties.  Unauthorized reproduction, distribution or alteration      //
//    of this source code, or any portion of it, may result in severe       //
//    civil and criminal penalties and will be prosecuted to the maximum    //
//    extent possible under the law.                                        //
//                                                                          //
//  Skylights 9.4b-6E                                    www.navitaire.com  //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-->

numRoutes=2;
        r1destination=DEL;
        r1origin=BOM;

        r1fareLabel=Regular Fare            ;


            r1Pax1Type=ADT;

                                                r1Pax1DiscountBase= Rs 4,430.00 ;
                                                r1Pax1TotalFareCost= Rs 8,426.00 ;


                                                                                r1Pax1Tax1Amount= Rs 233.00 INR;


                            r1Pax1Tax1SummedAmount=233.00;


                                                 r1Pax1Tax1Desciption=Passenger Service Fee;







                                                                                r1Pax1Tax2Amount= Rs 2,800.00 INR;


                            r1Pax1Tax2SummedAmount=2800.00;


                                                 r1Pax1Tax2Desciption=Fuel Surcharge;







                                                                                r1Pax1Tax3Amount= Rs 50.00 INR;


                            r1Pax1Tax3SummedAmount=50.00;


                                                 r1Pax1Tax3Desciption=Transaction Charge;







                                                                                r1Pax1Tax4Amount= Rs 360.00 INR;


                            r1Pax1Tax4SummedAmount=360.00;


                                                 r1Pax1Tax4Desciption=Service Tax;








                                                                                r1Pax1Tax6Amount= Rs 553.00 INR;


                            r1Pax1Tax6SummedAmount=553.00;


                                                 r1Pax1Tax6Desciption=User Development Fee;






                                                r1Pax1TotalTaxAmount= Rs 3,996.00 ;



                           r1Pax1SummedFareAmount=4430.00;



                                                r1Pax1SummedFareAmount=4430.00;
                                                r1Pax1SummedTaxAmount= Rs 3,996.00 ;



        r1InfDescription=;
                                r1InfDiscountBase= Rs 0.00 ;
        r1InfSSRCode=;
                                r1InfTotalFareCost= Rs 0.00 ;





                                r1TotalInfTaxAmount= Rs 0.00 ;
                                r1RouteTotalTax= Rs 3,996.00 ;
                                r1RouteTotalAmount= Rs 8,426.00 ;
                                r1InfSummedFareAmount= Rs 0.00 ;
                                r1InfSummedTaxAmount= Rs 0.00;
                                r1SummedTaxAmount= Rs 3,996.00 ;
                                r1SummedAmount= Rs 8,426.00 ;

        r2destination=BOM;
        r2origin=DEL;

        r2fareLabel=RoundTrip Fare          ;


            r2Pax1Type=ADT;

                                                r2Pax1DiscountBase= Rs 4,020.00 ;
                                                r2Pax1TotalFareCost= Rs 8,101.00 ;


                                                                                r2Pax1Tax1Amount= Rs 146.00 INR;


                            r2Pax1Tax1SummedAmount=146.00;


                                                 r2Pax1Tax1Desciption=Passenger Service Fee;







                                                                                r2Pax1Tax2Amount= Rs 2,800.00 INR;


                            r2Pax1Tax2SummedAmount=2800.00;


                                                 r2Pax1Tax2Desciption=Fuel Surcharge;







                                                                                r2Pax1Tax3Amount= Rs 50.00 INR;


                            r2Pax1Tax3SummedAmount=50.00;


                                                 r2Pax1Tax3Desciption=Transaction Charge;







                                                                                r2Pax1Tax4Amount= Rs 340.00 INR;


                            r2Pax1Tax4SummedAmount=340.00;


                                                 r2Pax1Tax4Desciption=Service Tax;








                                                                                r2Pax1Tax6Amount= Rs 745.00 INR;


                            r2Pax1Tax6SummedAmount=745.00;


                                                 r2Pax1Tax6Desciption=User Development Fee;






                                                r2Pax1TotalTaxAmount= Rs 4,081.00 ;



                           r2Pax1SummedFareAmount=4020.00;



                                                r2Pax1SummedFareAmount=4020.00;
                                                r2Pax1SummedTaxAmount= Rs 4,081.00 ;



        r2InfDescription=;
                                r2InfDiscountBase= Rs 0.00 ;
        r2InfSSRCode=;
                                r2InfTotalFareCost= Rs 0.00 ;





                                r2TotalInfTaxAmount= Rs 0.00 ;
                                r2RouteTotalTax= Rs 4,081.00 ;
                                r2RouteTotalAmount= Rs 8,101.00 ;
                                r2InfSummedFareAmount= Rs 0.00 ;
                                r2InfSummedTaxAmount= Rs 0.00;
                                r2SummedTaxAmount= Rs 4,081.00 ;
                                r2SummedAmount= Rs 8,101.00 ;

                TransactionFeeAmount=0.00; 
                TotalPackageAmount=Rs 16,527.00 ;
                PrefixType=Rs ;
```

Comment: Sorry, that was just a typo. I had post params also. Anyway, I tried with post_params, but the result was still the same. If you don't mind, can you please post the exact code that you used? I might have missed something very simple which I am not able to figure out. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I got it working finally. The issue was that there were some spaces in the post params which I thought were not required and had changed them to single space. Once I copied the exact post params with the exact number of spaces, it started working. Thanks Barmar for helping out.